# Почему мой webpack laravel.mix компилирует мои файлы по 10-20 секунд?

Tags: webpack, webpack4, laravel-mix

Всем доброго времени суток. Начал использовать laravel.mix для проектов, но столкнулся со стеной компиляции в over 10 секунд ><

Как заставить laravel.mix компилировать мои исходники хотя бы за секундочку?

мой webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.autoload({
  jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery']
});
mix.setPublicPath('./')
    .sass('src/scss/main.scss', 'dist/css')
    .sourceMaps()
    .js('src/js/main.js', 'dist/js')
    .extract(['bootstrap', 'popper.js', 'jquery' ]);

mix.browserSync({
  proxy: 'laravel.mix.li-lit'
});
```

Мой package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 3 version"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
        "cssnano": "^4.1.8",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.16.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.22"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "inputmask": "^4.0.6",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "swiper": "^4.4.6",
        "wowjs": "^1.1.3"
    }
}
```

Вот что говорит мой webpack, когда начинается компиляция scss(просто заменил бэкграунд и удалил):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что он говорит, когда скомпилил изменения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть пару моментов.

1. Структура и мощность проца (в идеале Intel i5 и выше, желательно стационарный, т.к. кеша больше чем в мобильном проце)
2. Сложность SASS. Если у вас много циклов, просчетов с переменными
3. sourceMaps очень удлиняет ребилд, особенно на скриптах (я бы рекомендовал его отключить)
4. Синхронизация тоже может добавлять пол секунды - секунду
5. Первый вотч делается дольше, чем потом

Но в первую очередь - процессор.

Это всегда так было или конкретно на каком-то проекте?
Если всегда - проц 100%, если проект - смотрите скрипты и выключите маппинг

i5 стационар, 8 гигов оперативки, Win7

[image: Прод]

__

прод с вуем и кучей скрипта (65 секунд)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вотч первый 22с, следующий 1,5с

Comment: сейчас сижу на macbook air i5 4gb оперативки, 1 - 3 секунды на компиляцию тратится. Раньше сидел на samsung с amd a10 8gb оперативки и вот на нем все конкретно долго, тоже склонюсь к процессору.